# msieve installation asks to pick a target

Tags: c, linux, shell, installation, makefile

I'm trying to install [msieve](https://github.com/radii/msieve)  following [this guide](https://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=23085).

But as soon as I type `make all` the scripts returns a message:

```
pick a target:
x86       32-bit Intel/AMD systems (required if gcc used)
x86_64    64-bit Intel/AMD systems (required if gcc used)
generic   portable code
add 'ECM=1' if GMP-ECM is available (enables ECM)
add 'CUDA=1' for Nvidia graphics card support
```

What am I supposed to do?

`make all ECM=1 NO_ZLIB=1` and `make all ECM=1` aren't working

Comment: `make all x86 ECM=1` or `make all x86_64 ECM=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in [this guide](https://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=23085) (link copied from the original question), the author says:

> Download the msieve package:
> Code:
>
> ```
> svn co https://svn.code.sf.net/p/msieve/code/trunk $HOME/Math/msieve
> ```

But I think you didn't do that. You chose to use an 12-year-old version (v1.46) of `msieve` from [some fork on Github](https://github.com/radii/msieve) (link also copied from the original question). In 12 years, a lot of things can change, including build procedures.

So I'd suggest you follow your guide more closely, either using the exact command shown above, possibly modifying the local repository path, (which will give you the trunk version, msieve 1.54) or in spirit, by downloading the source repository from [the msieve sourceforge page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msieve/), which will give you version 1.53, released in 2016. Whichever of the above you chose, the instructions you have should work.

Alternatively, you could follow the instructions in the version you downloaded, and change the `all` in `make all` to one of the three options listed (`x86`, `x86_64`, or `generic`), probably `x86_64` (assuming you're using a 64-bit Linux, which has been the norm for some years now).

Comment: Thank you @rici. I will check later on today. I taught the GitHub repository was the one as I was linked there form a math professor. Also, I was doing this on Windows and I didn't know it could not work there. Thank you